# VSTest Source filter changed and now tests are not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I recently noticed that the unit tests step in our pipeline stopped working correctly, what I see now is that the value for the Source Filter changed from `**\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**` to  `**\bin\**\*test.dll,**\bin\**\*tests.dll` and we don't have a bin folder in our output, other change I saw was the version for VSTest@2 from 2.198.0 to 2.227.0.

I'm not sure if that could cause the change in the Source filter value, I couldn't find any place to set it.

Any idea in how to fix it would be very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specific the Source file by using testAssemblyVer2.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

In addition, if you didn't set the source filter, the default value has been changed to `**\bin\**\*test.dll,**\bin\**\*tests.dll`.
This issue seems caused by the update of VSTest Task.

Comment: Thanks, I set testAssemblyVer2: '**\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**' but still getting the same error: ##[warning]No test sources found matching the given filter '**\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**'

Comment: Setting testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*Test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
in multiple lines did it for me 

 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
testAssemblyVer2: | 
  **Test.dll 
  !***TestAdapter.dll 
  !**\obj**
```

with the multiple line format fixed our issue.

¯\*(ツ)*/¯